# Ftp Upload gives exception Unable to write data to the transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, exception, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I have a windows form application in which i am using a background worker to ftp upload files. After uploading `209` files successfully it gave error on file which only had size of 7.8kb that `While Processing Img1.jpg Unable to write data to the transport connection. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`.

```
string uri1;

ftpInfoUpload = LoadHostedSiteData(hs);
ftpInfoUpload[5] = imgRow["Filename"].ToString();

uri1 = String.Format("ftp://{0}/{1}/images/{2}", ftpInfoUpload[1], ftpInfoUpload[2], ftpInfoUpload[5]);

requestUpload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri1);
requestUpload.UsePassive = false;
requestUpload.UseBinary = true;
requestUpload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
requestUpload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpInfoUpload[3], ftpInfoUpload[4]);


requestUpload.ContentLength = memStream.Length;
byte[] buff = new byte[bufferSize];
int contentLen;

// Stream to which the file to be upload is written
Stream strm = requestUpload.GetRequestStream();
memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
contentLen = memStream.Read(buff, 0, bufferSize);
                            // Till Stream content ends
while (contentLen > 0)
{   
    // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP   Upload Stream
    strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
    contentLen = memStream.Read(buff, 0, bufferSize);
}

//Close the file stream and the Request Stream
strm.Close();
strm.Dispose();
ftpStream.Close();
memStream.Close();
//responseUpload.Close();
responseDownload.Close();
```

And ideas whats happening?

Comment: You probably exceeded a quota on the FTP server so it aborted the connection.  Contact the server admin for support.

Comment: @HansPassant quota for number of files? servers have a quota for the number of files user can transfer?

Comment: probably not. Rather a quota for the total amount of trafic you caused (depending on the size of the files you uploaded) or just a simple connection reset

Comment: @yas4891 assuming its that case, how would you suggest i deal with it please?

Comment: put the files into a queue, transfer the queued items and handle exceptions by reconnecting to the server and re-transmitting the remaining files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set `ftprequest.KeepAlive=true` & set `ftprequest.ConnectionGroupName = "Some Value"`, so that underlying code does not have to new create connection which have the same ftp server. I found this solution [here](http://markitup.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=c98db0ca-f3a8-4f49-bb96-641574274c1a). I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016690/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-ftpwebrequest) helpful. Also make sure not to create a new `NetworkCredential` object everytime you transfer a file that can cause exception. I have tested my code twice transferring 300 files and seems to work perfectly and quick. Setting `KeepAlive=false` can make transfers slow