# vb.NET Network.UploadFile Limit

Tags: vb.net, upload, limit

i use **My.Computer.Network.UploadFile** method for file upload to FTP .
But i have some problem . My problem is Upload Speed .

Ex: i use some FTP program (FileZilla) and my upload speed 4 Mb/sn.
but **My.Computer.Network.UploadFile** method is **1.20Mb/sn limit .**

Why this method is limited ? Can i up Upload speed ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code pal and inform me if this will be useful:

```
        using System.Net;
             // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/" + "C:/XXXXX.zip");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "PassWord");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            FileStream file = File.OpenRead("C:/XXXXX.zip");

            int length = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            int bytesread = 0;

            do
            {
            bytesread = file.Read(buffer,0,length);
            ftpStream.Write(buffer,0,bytesread);
            }
            while(bytesread != 0);

            file.Close();
            ftpStream.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Uploaded Successfully");
```

Comment: FtpWebRequest's speed is 700-800 kb/sn . Any idea ? Maybe app.config edit ?

Comment: please inform me if these options changes the result (some of them are bound to your FTP server configurations)       Request.UseBinary = true;
Request.UsePassive = true;
Request.KeepAlive = true;

Comment: not changed ( 700-800 kb-sn ). its very interesting. i use ftp.exe and speed 4 - 6 mb/sn now .

Comment: may this being useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016690/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-ftpwebrequest